# I am building next js application the page works on local but when I deploy it in Vercel following error occurs

Tags: next.js, runtime-error, node.js-fs, dgrams

I have updated npm install and also mongodb. I have researched on google but didn't get any solution. I am using next js version 14. It works on local but when i deploy it in Vercel error occurs. Is there any ways to deploy this other than Vercel. I also try this in github it also failed.

[image: Screenshot]